# How to create add Oracle Weblogic's NodeManager as a service to xinetd?

Tags: boot, vmware-fusion

I'm trying to add NodeManager to start automatically when system boots
In Oracle® Fusion Middleware Node Manager Administrator's Guide there is this template:

```
# default: off
# description:nodemanager as a service
service nodemgrsvc
{
   type            = UNLISTED
   disable         = no
   socket_type     = stream
   protocol        = tcp
   wait            = yes
   user            = <username>
   port            = 5556
   flags           = NOLIBWRAP
   log_on_success += DURATION HOST USERID
   server          = <path-to-jave>/java
   env             = CLASSPATH=<cp> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<ldpath>
   server_args     = -client -DNodeManagerHome=<NMHome> <java options> 
   <nodemanager options> weblogic.NodeManager -v
}
```

I don't know how to fill:

- cp
- ldpath
- java_options
- nodemanager options

Do you have any xinetd script example to start nodemanager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this script worked for me:

```
# default: off  
# description:nodemanager as a service  
service nodemgrsvc  
{  
        type = UNLISTED  
        disable = no  
        socket_type = stream  
        protocol = tcp  
        wait = yes  
        user = oracle  
        port = 5556  
        flags = NOLIBWRAP  
        log_on_success += DURATION HOST USERID  
        server = /usr/bin/java  
        env = CLASSPATH="/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw/patch_wls1032/profiles/default/sys_manifest_classpath/weblogic_patch.jar:/u01/app/oracle/jrmc-3.1.2-1.6.0/lib/tools.jar:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw/utils/config/10.3/config-launch.jar:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic_sp.jar:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.jar:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw/modules/features/weblogic.server.modules_10.3.2.0.jar:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/webservices.jar:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw/modules/org.apache.ant_1.7.0/lib/ant-all.jar:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw/modules/net.sf.antcontrib_1.0.0.0_1-0b2/lib/ant-contrib.jar::/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw" LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw/patch_wls1032/profiles/default/native:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw/wlserver_10.3/server/native/linux/x86_64:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw/wlserver_10.3/server/native/linux/x86_64/oci920_8"  
        server_args = -DNodeManagerHome=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw/wlserver_10.3/common/nodemanager -client -Xms128m -Xmx256m  -Xverify:none  -Djava.security.policy=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.policy -Dweblogic.nodemanager.javaHome=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18  weblogic.NodeManager -v  
}
```

For the classpaths you'll need to know that I have these variables set:

```
$MW_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw  
$WL_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw/wlserver_10.3  
$JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18
```

But I still have the problem that I can't startup the managed servers (soa_server and bam_server). It is not documented anywhere and I don't know how to do it.

I need that when I restart the machine all servers are up.

**Thanks in advance**